# MSBuild exited with code 1 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, post-build-event

I am getting following error when trying to build the solution.

```
Error       The command "

      copy "D:\Code\..\libs\xyz_ext.x64.dll" "D:\Code\bin\"

      copy "D:\Code\..\libs\xyz.x86.dll" "D:\Code\bin\"

      " exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4714
```

Comment: Typically I copy the command that failed into a cmd prompt and run it manually to determine why it is failing. You might also consider using the visual studio environment variables instead of hard coding the path to the assembly.

Comment: The standard Windows error code 1 is invalid function. Is there anything else in the output?

Comment: is this the real command (including \..\) from the post build event?

Comment: @sahil, any update for this question? Could you get any useful info from below answer? If not, please let us to know the latest status for this issue.

Comment: I was not able to resolve it, i took duplicate version of code and it started working

Answer (score 0):

> MSBuild exited with code 1 error

First, just as nozzleman comment "*is this the real command (including ..) from the post build event*" If yes, this is the reason why you got this error. That because build events follow the same syntax as DOS commands, and DOS never supported wildcard `*` expansion and `\..\` in the path by the shell. So you should specify the full path in the command line.

Besides, if you want to copy the file in all the subfolders of `Code`, you need some way using existing windows tools (cmd.exe), or powershell with wildcard `*`, for example, powershell:

This is code in the .ps1 file:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Code\*\libs" -Recurse -Include xyz_ext.x64.dll | Copy-Item -Destination D:\Code\bin
```

Then execute this PS script by post build event:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file D:\Code\Test.ps1
```

If `\..\` is nor the real command from the post build event, just a shorthand expression. You should check the path of this command. According to the error log "`code 1 error`", it specify that this command is incorrect. And I have checked this command, the syntax of copy is correct, so the problem is the path is not incorrect, you should double check it.